# MVC combined with WebAPI in ASP.NET Core, but where are the Views?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to come to grips with the new ASP.NET Core 1.0 which states that both ASP.NET Web API and ASP.NET MVC are combined into one framework. So I decided to create a new ASP.NET Core Web API application using the ASP.NET Web API template from Visual Studio 2015.

But when I looked at the generated files/folders, there is no Views folder. The ValuesController is generated. I even added my own Controller which returns Web API responses. But I should also be able to add actions in my controller that returns, say, partial views as well right?

Since these two were merged, I assume I should be able to see a Views folder but I don't. How do I add the MVC parts to an app that was created using the Web Api template?

Comment: you don't need views for Web API

Comment: @Ray Better you start with MVC template and then add WebApi into it. This way you get all those Views and hierarchies and adding WebApi to that would be much simpler.

Answer (score 5):

You can add a `Views` folder manually by following these steps:

1. Create a `Views` folder.
2. Create `_ViewStart.cshtml` in the `Views` folder with this content:

```html
@{
  Layout = "_Layout";
}
```

3. Create a `Shared` folder inside the `Views` folder.
4. Create `_Layout.cshtml` inside the `Shared` folder with this content:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Web App</title>

</head>
<body>

    @RenderBody()

</body>
</html>
```